# ExtJS File Upload accept-headers

Tags: json, extjs, http-headers

I took the sencha file upload example from here

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/file-upload.js

(last example) and edited it to my needs.

I don't use PHP, but MS WebAPI. WebAPI returns whichever format the browser requests, so one has to set the accept-header to "application/json" to definitely get json in all browsers. Which is what I tried:

```
filefield.up('form').getForm().submit({
    url: '../api/AdminPanel/FileUpload',
    headers: {'Accept':'application/json'},
    waitMsg: 'Uploading logo...',
    success: function(fp, o) {
        Ext.getCmp("logo").setSrc=o.result.logoFile;
        msg('Success', 'Processed file "' + o.result.file + '" on the server');
    }
});
```

But somehow my "headers" are not used to send the data; instead the browser default accept-headers are sent. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have to change my question a bit.

I since found out that it is impossible to change headers on file upload.

So now my question is, how can I access the errorReader jsonData from `failure:function(fp, o)`?

Comment: are you sure the server returns right format? this is microsoft, you can't trust what they return

Comment: I trust firebug to show me the request headers as they are sent to the server.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.form.action.Submit

Read the note: it says headers are NOT sent during upload... How can you send them? Well, that question bought me here as well and so far, I don't know either...

Comment: @Lawrence As I said in the edit, it is impossible to send headers during upload.